# Dialog slide from the bottom - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show a dialog similar to the one that Google Maps app shows when the user select a place on the map. You can see it in Figure 1, Figure 2 and Figure 3. This dialog is like a Fragment which I can show in fullscreen and partial mode and I can slide out when I don't want to see it anymore. In this moment I only have a dialog with an animation that have a style when a dialog is prompted and another one when the dialog is dismissed, which you can see in Figure 4. This is not the expected behaviour because I want to interact with the dialog and not apply a simple animation.

**Questions**

1. I think the Google Maps dialog is like a Fragment, but I don't know how I can to show it partially and then show it in fullscreen mode. ¿Can I do this with a Fragment? ¿Can I deactivate the slide of the ViewPager parent only to this Fragment?
2. ¿Do you have any other suggestion to do a dialog like the Google Maps app's dialog?

Thanks.

**Figure 1**
[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 2**
[image: Figure 2]

**Figure 3**
[image: Figure 3]

**Figure 4**
[image: Figure 4]

Comment: See [this](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem adapting some elements of [this](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/) (thanks to Saif Hamed) and managing touch events to animate the dialog. It's not perfect because the animation is not very fluid but it works. This is the code involved:

i) I overlay the dialog layout to the camera layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/cameraPreviewFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <!-- Camera Preview -->

            <com.easyshopping.activities.CameraPreview
                android:id="@+id/cameraSurfaceView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </com.easyshopping.activities.CameraPreview>

            <!-- Dialog layout -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layoutDialogProduct"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutUpRegister"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewLabelNickname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="@string/label_register_nickname" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextNickname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName" >
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutMediumRegister"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutUpRegister"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewLabelEmail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="@string/label_register_email" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutBottomRegister"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutMediumRegister"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewLabelPassword"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="@string/label_register_password" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnOkRegister"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutBottomRegister"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:text="@string/positive_button" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCancelRegister"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/layoutBottomRegister"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:text="@string/negative_button" />
            </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

ii) Animation and touch events

```
// DIALOG SLIDER

    // Effects when overlay layout
    final OvershootInterpolator intp = new OvershootInterpolator();

    // Animation duration
    final int d = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

    // Dialog layout
    final RelativeLayout layoutDialogProduct = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutDialogProduct);

    // ViewTreeObserver of dialog to get its height
    ViewTreeObserver vto = rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutDialogProduct).getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            headerDialogHeight = rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutDialogProduct).getHeight();

            // Removel OnGlobalLayoutListener
            ViewTreeObserver obs = rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutDialogProduct).getViewTreeObserver();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            // ViewTreeObserver of cameraview to get its height

            ViewTreeObserver vto2 = mPreview.getViewTreeObserver();
            vto2.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    heightCameraView = mPreview.getHeight();

                    // Get spacing error when show the dialog
                    int tY = heightCameraView - headerDialogHeight;

                    // Remove ViewTreeObserver
                    ViewTreeObserver obs2 = mPreview.getViewTreeObserver();

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        obs2.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        obs2.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }

                    //Do animation
                    layoutDialogProduct.animate().translationY(tY).setDuration(d).setInterpolator(intp).start();

                }
            });

        }
    });

    layoutDialogProduct.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            viewPager.setmIsUnableToDrag(false);

            // float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE : {
                    // Hacer la animación

                    if (headerDialogHeight - y <= headerDialogHeight) {
                        layoutDialogProduct.animate().translationY(heightCameraView - headerDialogHeight + y)
                                .setDuration(d).setInterpolator(intp).start();
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            viewPager.setmIsUnableToDrag(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Screenshots
[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]